# Go: how to use sqlx to query two columns and map the data to key value pairs

Tags: go, sqlx

Imagine a query that returns the following:

```
+------------------------------------+---------+
|id                                  |user_type|
+------------------------------------+---------+
|0435b164-55ef-4b1a-8090-f75c3594332f|4        |
|0e1c17d5-d9df-4b5a-9310-431cfc8a6b36|4        |
|170202b6-7eb4-4242-9a3e-a4fc16daaccc|4        |
|19ff1812-5dd2-4707-a9de-125edf926ce5|4        |
|1a090e81-47ff-4d5c-b625-97c84043ff3a|4        |
+------------------------------------+---------+
```

What I want from this query is a `map[uuid.UUID]int` that has all of the id column values as keys, and the user type ints as the values.

Is this at all possible without a bunch of extra code? MapScan does not work and passing in the map value as the dest struct also fails.

Ideally the following or something similar works

```
var roles map[uuid.UUID]int
sqlx.Select(&roles, query)
```

Comment: There's no inherent correlation from the type of your id column (presumably `varchar`) and `uuid.UUID`, and there's no inherent correlation between the data set's first column and the map key. You have to write the code yourself; it isn't really that much. Scan into a slice of structs and build the map from there.

Comment: There may be more opinionated sql packages out there, but I'm not aware of any one in particular. With sqlx you can achieve this with, IDK, 10 lines of code?

Comment: @ScottClark please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    
    "github.com/google/uuid"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

func main() {
  var db *sqlx.DB
 
  db, _ = sqlx.Open("sqlite3", ":memory:")
 
  schema := `CREATE TABLE tmp (
      id integer,
      uuid text
  );`
 
  // execute a query on the server
  db.MustExec(schema)
 
  qry := `INSERT INTO tmp (id, uuid) VALUES (?, ?)`
  db.MustExec(qry, 1, uuid.NewString())
  db.MustExec(qry, 2, uuid.NewString())
  db.MustExec(qry, 3, uuid.NewString())
  rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT id, uuid FROM tmp")

  var tmp = make(map[string]int)

  // iterate over each row
  for rows.Next() {
      var id int
      var uuid string
      _ = rows.Scan(&id, &uuid)
      tmp[uuid] = id
      // fmt.Println(id, uuid)
      // rows.MapScan(&tmp)
  }
  fmt.Println(tmp)
}
```

Note: There is `MapScan` in sqlx which works with map but it can process 1 row at a time.